# JQuery plugin responsive menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, drop-down-menu

I'm fairly new to jquery and I'm trying to learn how to use it efficiently in a website. I'm working on a responsive navigation plugin that I found online. My problem with the plugin is that the drop down menu works but when it goes into mobile the arrow that activates the drop down menu does not work. Now, I don't know if I'm not starting the script correctly or what's wrong with the jquery script. Can anyone be kind enough to help and maybe explain why things are working or not working. Thanks!

```
<nav class="nav">
    <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
            <ul class="nav-submenu">
                <li class="nav-submenu-item">
                    <a href="#">STUDIO</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-submenu-item">
                    <a href="#">PORTRAITS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-submenu-item">
                    <a href="#">SPORTS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-submenu-item">
                    <a href="#">WEDDING</a>
                </li>
        <li class="nav-submenu-item">
                    <a href="#">ADVENTURE</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#">NEWS</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

jQUERY

;(function($) {

```
// DOM ready
$(function() {

    // Append the mobile icon nav
    $('.nav').append($('<div class="nav-mobile"></div>'));

    // Add a <span> to every .nav-item that has a <ul> inside
    $('.nav-item').has('ul').prepend('<span class="nav-click"><i class="nav-arrow"></i></span>');

    // Click to reveal the nav
    $('.nav-mobile').click(function(){
        $('.nav-list').toggle();
    });

    // Dynamic binding to on 'click'
    $('.nav-list').on('click', '.nav-click', function(){

        // Toggle the nested nav
        $(this).siblings('.nav-submenu').toggle();

        // Toggle the arrow using CSS3 transforms
        $(this).children('.nav-arrow').toggleClass('nav-rotate');

    });

});
```

})(jQuery);

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know much about Responsive Navigation Plug-in. But we need to handle touch events differently. You can just include library from http://touchpunch.furf.com for touch events.

If you are looking just context menu you can try using https://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu. It has ways to handle touch devices inputs.